# Docker - Ubuntu - bash: ping: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ping

I've got a Docker container running Ubuntu which I did as follows:

```
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

however it doesn't seem to have `ping`. E.g.

```
bash: ping: command not found
```

Do I need to install that?

Seems a pretty basic command to be missing. I tried `whereis ping` which doesn't report anything.

Comment: It's entirely appropriate for a Docker image to be minimal. In most cases, a container will never do anything but run a single application -- why install anything that application doesn't need?

Comment: This is not exclusive to docker images, the same issue is present in Ubuntu 22.X minimal server installer images (and maybe other versions too). I mean, who needs IP tools on their servers? 

Comment: my 5c: unless you _really_ need `ping` specifically (e.g. to measure latency precisely), use `wget` instead (which is provided via `/usr/bin/wget` in stock Ubuntu images routinely). `time wget` is not that precise, but if you're in a rootless docker, it's IMVHO the simplest and fastest way to check connectivity, DNS resolution and rough speeds.

Answer (score 1376, accepted):

Docker images are pretty minimal, but you can install `ping` in your official ubuntu docker image via:

```bash
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y iputils-ping
```

Chances are you don't need `ping` on your image, and just want to use it for testing purposes. Above example will help you out.

But if you need `ping` to exist on your image, you can create a `Dockerfile` or `commit` the container you ran the above commands into a new image.

Commit:

```bash
docker commit -m "Installed iputils-ping" --author "Your Name <name@domain.com>" ContainerNameOrId yourrepository/imagename:tag
```

Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping
CMD bash
```

Please note there are best practices on creating docker images, like clearing apt cache files afterwards and etc.

Comment: apt-get fails with `Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'` obviously because networking is not present.

Comment: I'd got into the habit of using `apt install` and ended up with "package not found", but as the answer says, `apt-get` works just fine.

Comment: If you need to install on a container running you need to execute with root privileges, so execute `docker exec -u 0 -it <container> /bin/bash`. Where `-u 0` is user root.

Comment: debian11: `E: Unable to locate package iputils-ping` :/

Comment: @jaques-sam i just tried it on debian:11.5 image and it worked. did you do `apt update` before hand?

Comment: Yeah, great idea. Except when you are trying to debug why `apt`/`apt-get` is failing...

Answer (score 81):

[This](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/) is the Docker Hub page for Ubuntu and [this](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/d4313e13366d24a97bd178db4450f63e221803f1/xenial/Dockerfile) is how it is created. It only has (somewhat) bare minimum packages installed, thus if you need anything extra you need to install it yourself.

```bash
apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping
```

However usually you'd create a "Dockerfile" and build it:

```bash
mkdir ubuntu_with_ping
cat >ubuntu_with_ping/Dockerfile <<'EOF'
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping
CMD bash
EOF
docker build -t ubuntu_with_ping ubuntu_with_ping
docker run -it ubuntu_with_ping
```

Please use Google to find tutorials and browse existing Dockerfiles to see how they usually do things :) For example image size should be minimized by running `apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` after `apt-get install` commands.

Comment: `echo -e` actually [defies the POSIX sh standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html), which doesn't allow it to do anything but print `-e` on its output. (Even with some versions of bash, that's the default behavior). Use `printf` instead: `printf '%s\n' "FROM ubuntu" "RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping" "CMD bash"`, and see the APPLICATION USAGE section of the above-linked standards document.

Comment: Even bash won't support `echo -e` the way you expect it to (but instead will have a standards-compliant behavior) when in POSIX mode compiled with `--enable-xpg-echo-default`, or with appropriate environment variables or other runtime configuration.

Comment: (POSIX allows echo to behave in an implementation-defined way when given `-n` as a first argument, or when any backslash literals are present -- but even then, it's *implementation-defined*, not standard-guaranteed, so behavior is dependent on the individual shell in use).

Comment: Thanks for comments and improvements, the "copy-and-paste" friendly example was more of an after thought.

Answer (score 22):

Alternatively you can use a Docker image which already has ping installed, e.g. [busybox](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox/):

```
docker run --rm busybox ping SERVER_NAME -c 2
```

Comment: It's a solution, but creating an image just to execute ping seems overkill for me. I'd rather ``apt-get iputils-ping`` on the image which needs it.

Answer (score 13):

Generally people pull the official image of Ubuntu/CentOS but they don't realize that these images are minimal and doesn't have any thing on the top of that.

For Ubuntu, this image is built from official rootfs tarballs provided by Canonical. Given that it is a minimal install of Ubuntu, this image only includes the C, C.UTF-8, and POSIX locales by default.

One can install net-tools (includes ifconfig, netstat), ip-utils(includes ping) andy other likes curl etc on container and can create image from container or can write Dockerfile that will install these tool while creating image.

Below is Dockerfile example, while creating image from this it will include these tools:

```
FROM vkitpro/ubuntu16.04
RUN     apt-get  update -y \
&& apt-get upgrade -y \
&& apt-get install iputils-ping -y \
&& apt-get install net-tools -y \
CMD bash
```

or launch container from base image and install these utilities on container and then commit to image.
docker commit -m "any descriptive message" container_id image_name:lattest

That image will have all thing installed.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, the minimal installation of Linux in Docker doesn't define the path and therefore it is necessary to call ping using ....

```
cd /usr/sbin
ping <ip>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have used the statement below on debian 10

```
apt-get install iputils-ping
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you get this kind of error

```
bash: <command>: command not found
```

- On a host with that command already working with [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394607/209677):

  ```
  dpkg -S $(which <command>)
  ```
- Don't have a host with that package installed? [Try this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6314/209677):

  ```
  apt-file search /bin/<command>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can run `ping` on the host after entering the container's network namespace.

First, find the container's process ID on the host (this can be the shell or the application you are running inside the container). Then change to the container's network namespace (run as `root` on the host):

```
host# PS1='container# ' nsenter -t <PID> -n
```

Modifying the `PS1` environment variable is only used to show a different prompt while in the container's network namespace.

Now you can use `ping`, `netstat`, `ifconfig`, `ip`, etc, given that they are installed on the host.

```
container# ping <IP>
container# ip route get <IP>
....
container# exit
```

Keep in mind that this only changes the network namespace, the mount namespace (file system) has not changed and therefore name resolving may not work correctly (it still uses the `/etc/hosts` file on the host)