# Docker, \"ping\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: docker

I have these two containers on the same network

```
docker inspect my_app_net
[
    {
        "Name": "my_app_net",
        "Id": "e136b758e8009e0361168aa0ead14ec85973c8d4f93e65122c22a2ff18f5e61f",
        "Created": "2018-03-22T21:11:51.781623693+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "a966584cd491caff18b25fa347b738a0853e5195ac517b5fb26bb019a271fc10": {
                "Name": "new_pizd",
                "EndpointID": "fdbacbbd564aeacccc57367dd082232e0498976ca485597b6ba8f6c82a0d4240",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "b36f350efca1f2e79bef8027a32f992021091fdd701e4d55d98af78984072150": {
                "Name": "new_nginx2",
                "EndpointID": "38731d2618aba0a7c63debd3b30a4c9b530d83a4fddbda97cdd2498298007120",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

When I try to ping the second from the first

```
docker container exec -it new_pizd ping new_nginx2 
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"ping\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

This is quite strange.
How can I check the docker variable $PATH? Which executable file does it refer to?
EDIT

Suggested answer asks for echo PATH,but it is the same as from my Ubuntu shell

```
docker exec -ti new_nginx2 echo $PATH
/home/milenko/eclipse:/home/milenko/miniconda3/bin:/home/milenko/bin:/home/milenko/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

And

```
milenko@milenko-System-Product-Name:~$ docker exec -ti new_nginx2 bash
root@b36f350efca1:/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

I have checked the bin,there is no ping inside

```
root@b36f350efca1:/bin# ls ping*
ls: cannot access 'ping*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check if this was it?

Comment: Using alpine would be the best solution instead of installing it. Tribid_bose answer works great. In fact Bret also tells the same thing.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The output

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"ping\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

means that the `ping` command was not found (either `$PATH` is misconfigured, or `ping` is not available, or something else).

> How can I check the docker variable $PATH?

Run <s>`$ docker exec -ti <CONTAINER> echo $PATH`</s>, it should output something like the following

**Edit**: should be `$ docker exec -ti <CONTAINER> bash -c 'echo "$PATH"'`

```
/home/user/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

`$PATH` is an environment variable set in *nix shells, it contains the directories where executables are looked up.

> Which executable file does it refer to?

As it says in the error output, the `ping` executable. Once you know the content of `$PATH`, you can check what the problem is (`ping` should be in `/bin`, at least on the containers I have here atm), and try to solve it.

To open an interactive console to inspect/work on the container, run `$ docker exec -ti <CONTAINER> bash`.

---

**Update**

> I have checked the bin,there is no ping inside

You probably have to install `iputils-ping`, see the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901311/docker-ubuntu-bash-ping-command-not-found), but basically (assuming your container is based on Debian or Ubuntu or similar distribution) run

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install iputils-ping
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, it should really be `docker exec -ti <CONTAINER> bash -c 'echo "$PATH"'`, otherwise your shell expands `$PATH`. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 27):

First enter the bash in the container # 1

```
docker container exec -it CONTAINER bash
```

In bash, type

```
apt update
```

then,

```
apt install iputils-ping
```

then,

```
exit
```

then type the ping command and it should work fine

e.g. `docker container exec -it new_pizd ping new_nginx2`

Comment: If you want to perform ping from both the containers to each other, you need to install ping on both the containers as well.

Comment: If you want to ping one container from the other container then both of them should be on the same network created by you. It does not work in the default network.

Answer (score 6):

Step -1

```
docker container exec -it mynginx ping newnginx
```

if above step giving error

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting
> container process caused "exec: "ping": executable file not found in
> $PATH": unknown

Step -2

```
docker container exec -it mynginx bash
```

Step-3

```
apt-get update
```

Step-4

```
apt-get install iputils-ping
```

Step -4

```
Exit()
```

Step-5

```
docker container exec -it mynginx ping newnginx
```

it will ping .

Answer (score 6):

May be your container is not having **ping**. login to that container using  `docker exec -it <Container_Name> bash`  this will open the bash inside your container. then type below commands.
`apt-get update;apt-get install iputils-ping;`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using nginx in docker container run command as nginx image doesn't have ping command, use nginx:alpine. nginx:alpine image has ping command associated with it. Example follows

```
docker container run --name new_nginx2 -d --network my_app_net nginx:alpine
```

Comment: Should be the answer. most simple solution.