# Ping won't install inside a Docker container

Tags: docker

I pulled the [Apache httpd image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd) and ran a container. However, once, I'm inside a container, ping doesn't work and I see an error: "bash: ping: command not found". Can't even ping 127.0.0.1. Ping is working outside of a container.

`cat /etc/resolv.conf` shows the same nameserver, inside and outside of the container. I restarted the Docker service, but, it doesn't solve the problem either.

```
docker pull httpd
docker run -d --name testweb httpd
docker exec -it testweb /bin/bash
ping google.com

root@fb1ce4bccc11:/usr/local/apache2# ping google.com

bash: ping: command not found
```

I tried to install Ping, but the package manager can't find it:

```
root@fb1ce4bccc11:/usr/local/apache2# yum -y install iputils-20160308-10.el7.x86_64
bash: yum: command not found
```

Comment: It depends what package manager the upstream image has installed. If it is not `yum`, then it might be `apt` or `apk` or something else. Would you point to the image you are using on Docker Hub?

Comment: I don't know how can I point to the image, that I'm using on Docker Hub. However, I do know the ID of the image, by running docker images, command. b7cc370ac278

Comment: OK, what was the name of the image? `docker pull <something>`. You should be able to get the name from the `docker images` command too.

Comment: docker pull httpd

Comment: OK, see the link I added to your post - that is where you are pulling it from. [The Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/75e85910d1d9954ea0709960c61517376fc9b254/2.4/Dockerfile) shows it is based on Ubuntu, so try `apt install -y iputils-ping` instead.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package iputils-ping

Comment: Heh, nearly there. Try `apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y iputils-ping`. Bonus points for you if you can tell me what this does `:-)`

Comment: wow. It worked. Thank you very much for your time and help @halfer By the way, how did you figure out, the image is based on Ubuntu.

Comment: You are welcome. From your image name, I followed the `Dockerfile` link, and found the `FROM` line at the top. I made a mistake, it is Debian, not Ubuntu, but they are pretty much the same thing. The parent image is `debian:stretch-slim`. They both use the Apt dependency manager.

Comment: So, for your learning, what do those commands do? It's OK if you don't know, but it is good to learn (and it is necessary to learn if you are going to be using Docker).

Comment: *FROM* tells the source of the image, so, in our, case, it is debian:stretch-slim. *ENV* represents environment variable. That's all I know when it comes to knowing Dockerfile. I very new to Docker.

Comment: I meant the `apt-get` commands, but yes, the Docker directives are worth studying too. Try building and running your own image when you can.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker - Ubuntu - bash: ping: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901311/docker-ubuntu-bash-ping-command-not-found) (thanks to Manfreds3 for finding it).

Comment: To my understanding, apt-get is similar to yum install. apt-get is used on Ubuntu based systems.

Comment: `apt-get update` refreshes the local software catalogue of what software is available in the remote OS mirror; `apt-get upgrade` installs the latest version of things that are installed but not at their latest version, and `apt-get install` installs things (generally at the latest available version) for things that are not installed at all. The install originally failed because you didn't have a local software catalogue until the `update` is run.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found a similar post: [Docker - Ubuntu - bash: ping: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901311/docker-ubuntu-bash-ping-command-not-found)

My first choice would be running:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install iputils-ping
```

Comment: *Note*: to work correctly, the second command requires a `-y`. 
This parameter is necessary to confirm the installation automatically.