# starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: bash, docker, mariadb

```
e44671200b7c /# mysql -u root -p bash 

mysql: command not found
```

I was able to enter into the container "mariadb" using

```
docker exec -it e44671200b7c /bin/bash
```

but i couldn't and i have this now error

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Comment: Hey! Please try to improve your question. I have read it several times, but I still don't get what did you mean to ask here. Probably you will find this guide useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also be sure you don't do something like `docker ... -v /my/binaries:/bin`.

Answer (score 33):

`bash` is not present in `mariadb` Docker image. Use `docker exec -it e44671200b7c /bin/sh` or simply `docker exec -it e44671200b7c sh` instead.

Comment: i tried too but i want to get into the container 
i was able to get into the container but when i trie to fix that " mysql: command not found "

Comment: Similar issue, that's because `mariadb` does not have `mysql` binaries installed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901311/docker-ubuntu-bash-ping-command-not-found. You seem new to Docker, maybe you should try to understand how a Docker image works and how to install/use packages in a Docker image, here's a good start: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

There are few images which do not support the interactive shell/bash. Example - Docker image mockserver/mockserver Docker Set Up

[Docker Setup Page for MockServer](https://www.mock-server.com/where/docker.html)